# SQL Select list of last records with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

| ID | Name | CodSituation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 2 | Mary | 2 |
| 3 | Mary | 3 |
| 4 | Mary | 4 |
| 5 | John | 5 |
| 6 | John | 2 |
| 7 | Mary | 1 |

I want to select the Names, ID's and CodSituation for all users where their last entry is CodSituation=2

In these results I will get just the id 6 As Mary's last entry was CodeSituation=4
if more than one users have their latest CodSituation=2 I want them too.

Comment: "*I will get just the id 6*", how you did this?

Comment: I didn`t , I want to do

Comment: Sorry I am not really getting what you need here!! Can you please post the expected output from the above sample data and based on what ?

Comment: In the sample above I want just the row with id 6

Comment: You mean `Select * from TableName where Id=6` ??

Comment: look this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/772650, in this schema I want to get just the John,mary and lucy rows 6, 9 and 14

Comment: I want to select just the people whose last codsituation = 2

Comment: Ya. got it :) Check my answer

Comment: Despite the chosen answer, I'll use the concatenating function in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easier way  concatenating fieds and using max solve this problem... Thanks!

```
SELECT
right(
max(
right(('0000000' + CONVERT(varchar,id) + '-'+ convert(varchar,codsituation)),4)),10),
name
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY name
HAVING 
right(
max(
right(

  ('0000000' + CONVERT(varchar,id) + '-'+ convert(varchar,codsituation))
  ,4)),1) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dc1c/10

Comment: I edited your question to reflect what you needed to know: you want an inner join.

Answer (score 8):

[FINAL EDIT]
After seeing what was posted at the end of this answer I figured out that the user was asking the wrong question:

What they were asking was 'show me everyone who has CodSituation=2' when they meant 'Show me all the users who's last entry in CodSituation field=2'

Here is the correct query for that:

```
select a.ID, a.Name, a.CodSituation
from table_name a
inner join (
    select Name, max(ID) as MaxID
    from table_name
    group by Name
) b on a.Name = b.Name and a.ID = b.MaxID 
where a.CodSituation = 2;
```

Here is the fiddle for that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a731d
[END]

[here are the previous queries, for reference]
Looks to me like you just need:

```
select * from table_name where CodSituation=2
```

To get all of the people with situation 2

To get only the last entry using mysql:

```
select * from table_name where CodSituation=2 order by id desc limit 1
```

To get the last entry using sql-server:

```
select top 1 * from table_name where CodSituation=2 order by ID desc;
```

See a working example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/022fb/4

[edit]

OP supplied an actual dataset:

```
select Name from table_name where CodSituation=2 group by Name;
```

This shows all the unique users with a CodSituation of 2 (with one entry per person)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be404/2

Comment: Post tagged as `sql server`.

Comment: sorry, missed that - added in sql-server syntax too

Comment: this doesn't solve my question because I need all people with codsituation in their last entry, this query that you show me returns only the last person

Comment: in this way, I`ll get all registers with codsituation = 2, I want just the register that have cod =2 in their last entry

Comment: not sure what you mean, you have 3 columns, id, name and 'CodSituation' there is no column called 'situation' or 'cod', unless you need to edit your question to provide more information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51838/discussion-between-jonathan-and-luckasx)

Comment: quoting myself "I want to select just the people that are with actual situation '2'." =D

Comment: What of these options is better in performance (nested join vs max and right) and why?

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved like this, but may not be the best way to do this

Basically what I am doing is Create a temporary table and add the Name and Maximum row number.

Which then match again that the maximum row number row is associated with CodSituation=2

```
 Create Table #Temp2(Name Varchar(10),RowN int)

;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) 
             FROM TableName)

insert into #Temp2         
SELECT Name,MAX(RN)
FROM CTE
Group By Name

select TT.*
from 
(
    SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) 
             FROM TableName
)TT
cross apply (
            select Name
            from #Temp2 TB
            where TB.Name=TT.Name and TB.RowN= TT.RN
            ) Tab
Where CodSituation=2
```

Fiddle [Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3cd1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Put condition using "WHERE" clause and if you want last two records then use ORDER BY "ID" DESC LIMIT 2